# Печать из RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, самый простой способ распечатать на принтере текст из RichTexBox'а. На msdn как-то много букв по этому поводу написано. Или так и надо?

Comment: Вот тут хорошо пишут:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/50924-use-a-print-dialog-box-to-print-contents-of-a-textbox/

Answer (score 2):

[Simplified .NET Printing in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9282/Simplified-NET-Printing-in-C)

> Uses a RichtextBox to cache our text for printing.

Comment: Будем надеяться, что через **`3/4`** года ТС'у пригодится ответ XD

Comment: В ссылке `e.Graphics.DrawString` - это что значит? В c# RichTextBox не умеет нормально отправлять на печать?

Comment: В этом ответе приведен "самописный" пример, который не совсем корректно работает (проблема с форматированием).