# Как сохранить форматирование при печати из richtextbox

Tags: c#, печать, richtextbox

Есть код для печати из richTextBox. Как сохранить форматирование при печати?

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument documentToPrint = new PrintDocument();
        printDialog.Document = documentToPrint;

        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
            documentToPrint.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(DocumentToPrint_PrintPage);
            documentToPrint.Print();
        }
    }
    private void DocumentToPrint_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
        float LinesPerPage = 0;
        float YPosition = 0;
        int Count = 0;
        float LeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float TopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        string Line = null;
        Font PrintFont = this.richTextBox1.Font;
        SolidBrush PrintBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        LinesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

        while (Count < LinesPerPage && ((Line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            YPosition = TopMargin + (Count * PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Line, PrintFont, PrintBrush, LeftMargin, YPosition, new StringFormat());
            Count++;
        }

        if (Line != null)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
        PrintBrush.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Richedit по идее должен печатать один к одному, если не считать некоторых глюков с рисунками и таблицами. Вы печатаете "самописной" процедурой или в чём проблема собственно?

Comment: Открывайте справку microsoft - MSDN и читайте раздел RichTextBox https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx пользуйтесь встроеной ф-цией печати.

Comment: У меня в richtextbox загружается файл rtf со своим форматированием. Эту процедуру взял на просторах инета. Вроде бы тут указывается шрифт. Но при печати получается просто текст без форматирования. В сохранении из richtextbox я указываю вот такой параметр: RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText и там всё ОК.

Comment: `e.Graphics.DrawString` - что это? Самописная печать? RichTextBox умеет печать. Если достаточно знаний - можно самому реализовать печать... но тогда шерстите все все все параметры форматирования.

Comment: эту процедуру рекомендую не использовать. Почитайте справку microsoft,  у RichTextBox есть встроена ф-ция печати.

Comment: Я не могу разобраться со встроенной функцией печати. Поэтому нашёл такой код. Может есть что то гораздо удобнее?

Comment: Есть тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/46282/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-richtextbox пара ссылок.

Comment: Я читал уже их) там по делу ничего не нашёл. Есть исходники из richtextbox, но... Увы без форматирования там... Помогите найти хотя бы просто готовые исходники с при печати

Comment: @Alias - ваша ссылка на wpf, а у топикстартера winforms.

Comment: Я думаю, [это](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/812425/how-to-print-the-content-of-a-richtextbox-control-by-using-visual-c-ne) поможет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov действительно, не увидел явного указания в тегах вопроса (

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо большое. Расширил класс. Сделал библиотеку. Подключил в проекте новый элемент. Всё работает. Но есть один косяк. Нужно ещё разобраться с параметрами печати. Если слишком большой документ, то верх обрезается